# No call back for Google identity services

Tags: google-identity

I was informed by google that the google_signin2 will be sunset and I need to move to their Identity Services.  Signin2 was working fine and using HTML with JavaScript. I am trying to get Google's example working and am not getting a call back after signing in.  The first time sign in prompts for a user/password and after that it redirects to a blank pop up without any call back to my page.  Each refresh brings me back to the blank pop up without going through the sign on again.  Signing out of google will re-prompt that.  So its authenticating properly just not calling back.  It seems like its stuck somewhere.  Here's my test page:

```
    <html>
      <body>
          <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async="true" defer></script>
          <script>
            function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
                alert("callback");
                console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
            }
            window.onload = function () {
                alert("init");
                google.accounts.id.initialize({
                    client_id: "MYID",
                    callback: "handleCredentialResponse"
              });
              google.accounts.id.renderButton(
                document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
                { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
              );
              google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
            }
        </script>
        <div id="buttonDiv"></div> 
        <h1>XXXX</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a SSL problem with my dev environment.  Per Google, the end point of the page must be accessible via a URL and use https.  The end point also has to be configured in the Google control panel, which it was.  I'm running on a local host and spoofed my dev URL to be dev environment but the cert had expired.  Now all is up to date and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you need to remove the quotes around your `callback` definition: `callback: "handleCredentialResponse"` -> `callback: handleCredentialResponse`

Comment: Didn't work.  This is verbatim from the Google sample code.